# Scala "does not contain" with String split

Tags: scala

I am trying Scala for the very first time, not sure how to filter based on `not contains`.
I have a below query;

```
.filter(_.get[Option[String]]("status") map(_ split "," contains "Pending") getOrElse(false))
```

But I want to do something like below;

```
.filter(_.get[Option[String]]("status") map(_ split "," does not contain "Pending") getOrElse(false))
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: I'd suggest to add sample input and expected output.

Comment: I would suggest making your code more readable by adding `.` and parenthesis and naming the lambdas arguments..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution;

```
.filter(_.get[Option[String]]("status") map(a => !(a split "," contains "Pending")) getOrElse(false))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists` and `forall` to simplify this. These functions return true if a condition is `true` for any or all elements of a collection.

So the pattern

```
Option[String].map(???).getOrElse(false)
```

can be

```
Option[String].exists(???)
```

And the condition

```
!(a split "," contains "Pending")
```

can be

```
a.split(",").forall(_ != "Pending")
```

Applying both of these to the original code gives

```
.filter(_.get[Option[String]]("status").exists(_.split(",").forall(_ != "Pending")))
```

But I would recommend a local function to clarify this code:

```
def notPending(s: String) = s.split(",").forall(_ != "Pending")

.filter(_.get[Option[String]]("status").exists(notPending))
```

This reads as "take all values where the status option exists and the status is not pending"